# Spring reactive Webclient timeout

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, spring-reactive

I was trying to test the default timeout of Spring reactive Webclient .
For that purpose I created a rest endpoint that takes 10 hours to return a response.

I created a rest client using spring reactive Webclient. But I see that the spring Reactive Webclient keeps waiting for 10 hours.

Doesn't spring reactive Webclient has any default timeout?

Comment: what is the default timeout of Spring reactive Webclient (asuming we don't give any timeout option as in our code)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Reactor Netty as HTTP client library which is default using Spring WebFlux there is no default response timeout specified. If you would like to configure timeout settings there are multiple options as described in the [Projectreactor reference documentation chapter 6.14](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_timeout_configuration).